# How can I define programmatically whether Office Web Apps is installed on server?

Tags: 2010, office-web-apps

I am using C# programming language and want to define whether Office Web Apps installed on server in order to hide/show *MenuItemTemplate*

My variant is as follows:

```
if(!Ispostback)
{
  bool b = File.Exists(@"C:\\Program Files\\Common Files\\Microsoft Shared\\Web Server     Extensions\\14\TEMPLATE\\LAYOUTS\\WordViewer.aspx"); 
  mit.visible=b;      //  mit- means <SharePoint:MenuItemTemplate>
}
```

but I need something else... what is the correct method?

Answer (score 1):

Search through the registry.

Here is one example from Stackoverflow:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/908850/get-installed-applications-in-a-system

Comment: `mit.Visible=GetInstalledApps();` from above mentioned link. Thank you very much Robban1980.

Comment: I changed Method to bool and here code snippet              `{ { using (RegistryKey sk = rk.OpenSubKey(skName))
                    {
                       
                      string s= (string)sk.GetValue("DisplayName");
                      if(s=="Microsoft® Office Web Apps")
                      {
                          return true;
                      }
                    }`}
                return false;
            }